# How to install python-binance into anaconda3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I activate my environment in the `Anaconda3` and then install `python-binance` package using `pip install python-binance` or pip3. Then I try to import it:

```
from binance.client import Client
```

But there is an error message:

```
 "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance'"
```

I set environment separately: `...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`. The `binance` folder is inside `site-packages` and client.py is inside: `binance` folder

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

conda does not offer this library. Therefore the best is to download it from the source and unzip and install into the folder: "...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages"

P.S.: path should be set.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make 3 installations following next setps

First of all, start installing pip with:

```
conda install pip
```

Second step:

```
conda install twisted
```

And finally:

```
pip install python-binance
```

Comment: This worked for me because it was the only way I could successfully install twisted.

Answer (score 2):

for me the easiest way was:

- open Anaconda Prompt (win button -> type: Anaconda Prompt)
- "pip install python-binance" ->Thats all.
- normaly pip is already installed. If not ->"conda install pip" and after this "pip install python-binance"

KR

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-binance
```

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-binance